# What toolbox to use to create multi-output random forest(reggression) with custom spltting function at each node?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, random-forest, multi-output

I am trying to implement "Real Time Head Pose Estimation fromConsumer Depth Cameras" by Fanelli et al.
I need to train a random forest(regression) with the following criterion

1. The predicted output is multivariate(yaw,pitch).
2. The input features is four dimensional float type.
3. The split function at each node is a custom function which needs to be computed at run-time using one of the features that has been randomly selected.
4. The custom function needs to evaluated using a separate user created code snippet which might then be used by the random forest code.

**My question is what random forest software frame work would support custom split functions and random feature selection for evaluating the custom function.**

I have checked random forest implementations of scikit-learn, opencv, weka to begin with, but found that they don't satisfy my constraints

Comment: Feel free to implement it yourself. A random forest is just an ensembling of decision trees. you can check how to build a decision tree from scratch in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6DmpG_PtN0&t=3s